# Can ping but cannot telnet to a local network computer

Tags: networking, ssh, port, telnet

This question follows [How to create a network over usb?](https://superuser.com/questions/1399755/how-to-create-a-network-over-usb/1399785?noredirect=1#comment2111611_1399785) .
I can ssh to a controller device. When I'm on it, I want to telnet to a running server on my computer. My computer and the device are connected through 2 USB-ethernet dongles.

I can ping my computer from the SSH but telnet is not working. What are the steps to follow ? My OS is archlinux so I suppose the ports are open.

Answer (score 0):

Do not assume telnet is open. For most of the distributions, a telnet server is not even installed unless you do it explicitly yourself. Telnet is considered to be an old protocol which sends text (including passwords) in clear over the network and it is therefore no longer seen as secure.

Unless there is a very specific reason to telnet, consider using ssh.

Comment: I can telnet. It works through the USB interface but not through the ethernet interface